# How to encapsulate a console exe file within a GUI app?

Tags: c++, windows, executable

I have a exe file that runs from DOS console. Is there a way to create a GUI a simple window with some input text boxes and associate this visual interface with the exe file?

The file runs from DOS like this.

```
Program1.exe a b inputfile > output.txt
```

I'd like to have a new exe, for example Program2.exe, with the Program1.exe contained inside and when I do double click ove Program2.exe launches the GUI that would let me select the Input file will produce Output.txt after the Program2.exe calls Program1.exe.

Is this possible with C, C++, Visual basic, java?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your console program "Program1.exe" in your drive, you can run it using the C function - [system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx):

```
system("Program1 a b inputfile > output.txt");
```

If you really want to store the console program in the GUI program, then you may store it as some binary resource/data and extract it to the drive during execution. Here are some ways to embed binary data in a C program: http://gareus.org/wiki/embedding_resources_in_executables

Answer (score 0):

Learning GUI programming would do good. There are many libraries that offer GUI programming like QT, GTK compatible with c++.

Comment: Hello Nishan, thanks for answer. But I want to know how to associate the console executable file I already have with GUI that I could create and how to call the executable from the GUI app. Basically, how to give a visual face(a window/GUI) to the console exe file. The exe file will remain inside the GUI app. I hope make sense. Thanks

Comment: that is nearest to impossible since the original exe file has different context within it, and there exist no mechanism to link the GUI part and the exe file separately without better understanding the source of that exe.
So, learn some GUI programming as i suggested

Comment: You can use a system call from within your GUI code I guess. Not very portable but you might not care.